# How to update table using LOAD INFILE?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
$this->db->query("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$file_path."' 

        INTO TABLE table1
        CHARACTER SET  utf8mb4
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','

        OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY  '\"' 
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 

        IGNORE 1 LINES 

        (Email,Jurisdiction_Parish,Jurisdiction_Ward,Jurisdiction_Precinct,Personal_FirstName,
        Personal_MiddleName,Personal_LastName,Personal_NameSuffix,Residence_HouseNumber,Residence_HouseFraction,Residence_StreetDirection,
        Residence_StreetName,Residence_ApartmentNumber,Residence_City,Residence_State,Residence_ZipCode5,Residence_ZipCode4,Mail_Address1,
        Mail_Address2,Mail_City,Mail_State,Mail_ZipCode5,Mail_ZipCode4,Mail_Country,Personal_Sex,Personal_Race,Registration_PoliticalPartyCode,
        Personal_Age,Registration_VoterStatus,Registration_Date,Registration_Number,Personal_Phone,LastVoted,Residence_WalkListOrder,
        Favorability,Yard_Sign,Comments,Personal_NameOrder,voted,Rating,Custom_Variable1,Custom_Variable2,Custom_Variable3)
        SET cid =".$cid.", csvsheet_id=".$csvsheet_id
        );
```

The above code for insert the data of CSV into database but i want to update the existing records of database from CSV. So How can i modified the query so that it will work for UPDATE the records.

Comment: Have you read the manual 'The REPLACE and IGNORE keywords control handling of input rows that duplicate existing rows on unique key values:' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html ?

Comment: actually i want to update the database records from the CSV file, so how can i update the records of database from the CSV file.

Comment: The closest load data infile gets to update is replace, if that doesn't work for you then you may have to write to a staging table and update from there, You can search for alternatives by googling mysql load data infile update , here's an example https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11811/mysql-csv-update-not-insert-into-existing-table

Answer (score 0):

1. You must defined primary or unique key for fields, which are responsible for the equality of records
2. You must add `REPLACE` keyword in `LOAD INFILE` statement

```sql
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'myfile' 
  REPLACE
  INTO TABLE table1
  CHARACTER SET  utf8mb4
  ................
```

Comment: How can i add the where condition ( the where condition match with CSV registration no to the database registration no)...??  Can you Please share the complete query for  LOAD DATA INFILE WITH REPLACE... Thanks..

Comment: @AmitGupta WHERE condition determined by primary/unique keys and not specified in query. The rest of the query is exactly the same as yours.

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing by                                                               
 $this->db->query("update table1 set voted = (select voted from table2 where table1.Registration_Number = table2.Registration_Number AND table1.cid = table2.cid)");
By the above query but it takes too much time to update the records (my records are in millions).  How can optimized this query...

Comment: @AmitGupta If my answer solved your problem - accept it. If you have any new questions - ask them in a separate topic.

Comment: i used the Replace key word in my query as you posted...but when i run the query it is not updating the collum of db but it inserted new rows in database... My CSV file contain only two field voted and Registration Number.

Comment: @AmitGupta What field should be updated? `Voted`? Does the field `Registration Number` have a primary or unique key?

Comment: there is a voted field in database only and the registration numbers are according to campaign_id may be dublicated in database so we have only cid(campaign_id) and registration no pair for unique

Answer (score 0):

i used the below code for update the existing records of database.

```
 LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'myfile' 
 REPLACE
 INTO TABLE table1
 CHARACTER SET  utf8mb4
```

But the problem is that in my CSV file i have only two column. When I Run the query it Updated the Records(voted column only) but others column has been blanked. Is is necessary to give all the column name with the data also..??